# Rocket League steam controller player 2 only

Tags: steam, rocket-league

Rocket league won't let me play as player 1 using my steam controller. It says "Press |> to join" and then goes into split screen mode.

Answer (score 5):

Disable desktop mode for the steam controller using the following steps:

Steam > View > Settings > Controller > Desktop Configuration >  Browse Configs > Show Other Controller Types

Choose one of the disabled ones (PS4 or Xbox) and apply it.

This will disable the mouse/keyboard emulation of the steam controller which apparently confuses Rocket League.

(found via [death2trollz@steamcommunity.com](http://steamcommunity.com/groups/homestream/discussions/0/451850468370036977/))

Comment: No luck for me on Linux. If I use the third-party sc-controller program to bind to the steam controller, everything works fine. Otherwise, the default Valve drivers exhibit the problem in this thread & disabling mouse/kb emulation of the steam controller doesn't do anything. Would prefer to not have to use sc-controller though, since it has some minor glitches.